# Opencv 3.1 compiled with FFMPEG, but won't open https urls

Tags: opencv, video, https, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I work on a 16.04 system, and have successfully installed opencv 3.1 with FFMPEG flags enabled. I double checked this was actually the case by cv2.getBuildInformation() and I got FFMPEG = YES.

I am trying to open a video that is hostel on a private server by my workplace (I am logged in to the VPN, in case thats a concern) and I can access this video over the browser. But videocapture with cv2 fails.

```
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture("https://xxx.mp4", cv2.CAP_ANY) #dummy url
>>> cap
<VideoCapture 0x7f63300fa4b0>
>>> cap.isOpened()
False
```

This is always the case for https urls. It seems to be able to work with local videos just fine. I have tried a bunch of different thing: initially thought it was a gstreamer problem so I checked my plugins, had some gst-bad versions (ref: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-ugly), removed those and replaced with good versions, no joy. Also tried to explicitly tell videoCapture to use cv2.CAP_ANY and cv2.CAP_FFMPEG flags while reading the video, still no luck.

I disabled the Gstreamer flag while compiling opencv, but even with it set to ON, there was no difference in my problem.

I haven't been able to find a solution to this issue and have been looking and trying different things for days now! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I gave up on trying to install and reinstall opencv3.1, and switched to opencv 3.4.1. With that, and my current (as original question post) configuration for gstreamer and ffmpeg, I only had to create symlinks for libopencv_core.so.2.4 that gstreamer was looking for, and the rest of it worked fine.

Hope this helps someone!

I haven't managed to figure out what exactly was the issue with opencv3.1 (like I mentioned, that is the configuration my other colleagues have, and the functionality works just fine for them) but this is what I ended up doing after spending days on the issue.